# What is the minimum Hardware insfracture required for spark to run on spark standalone cluster mode?

Tags: apache-spark

[image]I am running  spark standalone cluster mode in my local computer .This is hardware information about my computer

Intel Core i5
Number of Processors:   1 
Total Number of Cores:  2
Memory: 4 GB.

I am trying to run spark program from eclipse on spark standalone cluster .This is some part of my code .

```
  String logFile = "/Users/BigDinosaur/Downloads/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7 2/README.md"; // 
 SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setMaster("spark://BigDinosaur.local:7077"));
```

after running program in eclipse I am getting following warning message

**Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resource**

This is my screen shot of web UI

After going through other people answer on similar problem it seems like hardware resource mismatch is the root cause.

I want to get more  information on

**What is Minimum Hardware insfracture required for spark standalone cluster  to run application on it ?**

Comment: Do you have set something in the configuration files? I am able to run a simple Spark job on my Netbook Asus 1011px with 1 GB Ram and a Intel Atom.

Comment: And have you started at least one Worker using one of the skripts under the sbin folder?

Comment: If you really are limited by resources, you could try Databricks Community Edition.

Answer (score 1):

It started running after i run following command 
./start-slave.sh spark://localhost:7077  --cores 1 --memory 1g

I gave for core 1 and memory 1 g

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As per I know. Spark allocates memory from whatever memory is available when spark job starts.

You may want to try with explicitely providing cores and executor memory when starting job.